# Auto Formatting Race Result Times

Tags: vba, excel

I have started creating a VBA Macro that helps me add formatting to rows as I add them with a custom NumberFormat. But since My partner and I sometimes Enter item like "ss.00" and this messed up the cell. So I started writing out another Sub where it checks if its missing the semicolon. How can I add "0:" to the front of this value automatically where the cell would show "0:50.20", Everytime I do it, it ends up being a long number.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 1 Then
            If Target.Row < 24 And Target.Row > 1 Then
                Set FirstRow = Target.Offset(0, 1)
                Set LastRow = Target.Offset(0, 11)
                If Target.Value <> "" Then
                    For Each Cel In Range(FirstRow, LastRow)
                        Cel.NumberFormat = "m:ss.00;@"
                    Next
                Else
                    If MsgBox("This will erase the row! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        For Each Cel In Range(FirstRow, LastRow)
                            Cel.ClearContents
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

        Const sCheckAddress As String = "B2:L24"
        Dim rngIntersect As Range

            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Me.Range(sCheckAddress), Target)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not (rngIntersect Is Nothing) Then
                If Target.Value2 <> "" Then
                    If InStr(Target.Value2, ":") < 1 Then

                    End If
                End If
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would help you :

```
If InStr(Target.Value2, ":") < 1 Then
    ' ":" not found
    Target.Value = CStr("0:" & Target.Value)
Else
    ' ":" found
    'Nothing to add
End If
```

Comment: Ahh great! :)
I was looking for some info on NumberFormat parameters, did you change something?

Comment: It didn't work in WorkSheet_Change, but as soon as I placed it in WorkSheet_SelectionChange it works. You enter in a time, the cell will show 0:00.00 and when you select that, it'll change to the correct time :) Couldn't get it to work on Enter of Cell, but this is just as good haha